# Entity Framework SaveChanges() does not insert DateTime? when It's Specified

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, datetime

I have a class `MyEntity` with a `DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }` property.

So I create my Entity:

```
MyEntity e = new MyEntity { Id = 0, ..., CreatedDate = DateTime.Now };

db.MyEntities.Add(e);
db.SaveChanges();
```

I look in the database and the CreatedDate field is null. Why? I specified it right before adding to the context!

In tried others' suggestions of setting `CreatedDate = DateTime.Now as DateTime?`; or even `CreatedDate = DateTime.Now as Nullable<DateTime>;` Same result - inserting is null.

Comment: Please include the MyEntity class. Is your CreatedDate field mapped?

Comment: There's not enough info here, because as posted this should work.

Comment: What more code is necessary? class MyEntity { public DateTime? CreatedDate {get; set;} } should be sufficient, right? What does "mapped" mean? I thought it automatically migrates to the database with the same column name.

Comment: Are any other properties getting saved?

Comment: Yes. I have strings (which are nullable) and they save.

Comment: The `Id = 0,` part is unnecessary and undesriable but probably not the cause here.

Comment: Try `DateTimeOffset? CreatedDate { ...}` and when that works, worry about your exception handling.

Comment: This should absolutely work as shown. Is SaveChanges() throwing an exception?

Comment: @OP - can you check the SQL emitted for the insert?

Answer (score 1):

Could the issue be that in the first line of code you are declaring a new class of type Entity instead of MyEntity?

try..

```
MyEntity e = new MyEntity { Id = 0, ..., CreatedDate = DateTime.Now };

db.MyEntities.Add(e);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: OK, good typo catch, but it still doesn't save the CreatedDate.

Answer (score 0):

`CreatedDate = DateTime.Now.Date`

set the createddate as date

Comment: And why would that be better?

Comment: Lots of tutorials tell us to do this without explaining. All this would do is make the time 12:00 AM. The app might not care about the time, which this would work, but some apps do care.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tell you guys earlier but I had decorated DateTime? CreatedDate with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` which I didn't think affected create or update.

If I had this attribute, any in-C# effort to set `CreateDate` will result in null. To fix the null problem, I had to go to Configuration.cs and `write c => c.DateTime(defaultSqlValue: "GETDATE()")` to the corresponding column definition. Took care of the problem.

Alternatively, I could just get rid of the annotation and not touch the Configuration.cs file.

Comment: This will certainly affect create and update.  You're telling EF that this value will not be set by you, but will be generated by the database.

Comment: _"I didn't tell you guys earlier but I had decorated DateTime? CreatedDate with [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]..."_ - And this is the reason why _"more code was necessary"_! :)

Comment: We don't always know "what code is necessary to show" when we're just learning. Having to quote me this way is unnecessary roughness.

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint after entity instance creation and check properties. Is CreatedDate set properly?

Comment: I've set breakpoints until right before db.SaveChanges(), and indeed, CreatedDate was null when it got to the database. I figured out what was wrong. I had declared an annotation that would purposely disregard any in-code setting of CreatedDate.